# Definition Of $J$-tuple, $J$ is an Index Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let J be an index set. Given a set $X$, we define a J-tuple of elements of $X$ to be a function $x:J\to X$.

**Question:** When we define the notion of  J-tuple in terms of map, don’t we loose the notion of “order”(order list) on J-tuples of elements of $X$? From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_functions definition of J-tuple, when J is finite, map $F$ should be surjective. That is not the case, when J is an arbitrary index set. This is the reason, why I don’t like to define sequence in terms of map, even though it is formal way to define sequence. And saying a map is an element of $\Pi_{i \in I}X_{i}$ set, sound really absurd/unnatural to me.

Note I have mixed some notation from Wikipedia definition and Munkres’ definition.

Comment: How would you want to define it then? Yes, in a general index set there is no natural ordering. But this is still the natural generalization of finite cartesian products.

Comment: @Mark I am not giving idea to redefine the definition. Can we somehow write $J$-tuple in terms of sequence?

Comment: @Mark let say, for a moment, we ignore J-tuple. Defineing sequence(finite) as map, also arise the same problem.

Comment: @user264745 An (infinite) sequence is the same thing as an $\mathbb N$-tuple. I’m not sure what you mean regarding surjectivity… the map is surjective onto the set $\{x_j:j\in J\}$ just like how it is in the case $J=\{1,\ldots, n\}.$

Comment: @user264745 An infinite sequence of elements of $X$ is just a map $\mathbb{N}\to X$. Just like a tuple. The only difference is that in the special case $J=\mathbb{N}$ we have a natural ordering on the indexes. Same as finite sequences are maps $\{1,2,...,n\}\to X$.

Comment: @user264745 "... map $F$ should be surjective. That is not the case, when $J$ is an arbitrary index set" No, it is still surjective. I don't think you understood the definitions.

Comment: If by “problem” you mean “lose the order” that doesn’t happen in the finite case (or more generally for any ordered index set). The ordering is on the index set not its range. Association with the index set is how the elements of the sequence are “put in order”.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3438884.

Comment: I changed the tag to "elementary-set-theory" because your question has nothing to do with topology.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I’m still having a hard time reconciling tuple(map def) as sequence(ordered list). I have wrote “specific” question below Henno Brandsma answer, where exactly I’m having difficulty with map definition.

Comment: @PaulFrost yeah. I agree. Should I also remove Munkres Topology from the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $J$ has an order (say if $J=\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$, or $J=\Bbb N$) then we can sort of say the $J$-tuple $f: J \to X$ has an order too. The notation $(x_1,x_2)$ in a $2$-tuple in $X^2$ is just a shorthand for the function $\{1,2\} \to X$ defined by $f(1)=x_1$ and $f(2)=x_2$. The subscript notation or tuple notation is just another way of writing the function compactly.

The same way a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is just a function $f: \Bbb N \to X$ as well. The order (as used in convergence) purely comes from the index set/domain.

The function can be totally arbitrary (even constant or almost constant, or $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for an $\Bbb R$-tuple with values in $[0,1]$ e.g.

Products in set theory (hence in topology, analysis and algebra too) are just sets of functions. It is what it is.

**Added after comments**

We want to show $\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha \cap  \prod_{\alpha \in J} V_\alpha = \prod_{\alpha \in J} (U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha)$.

So let $f$ be in the LHS. So it is a function (i.e. a set of pairs) and as $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha$ for each fixed $\alpha$ there is a *unique* pair $(\alpha, x) \in f$ with $x \in U_\alpha$. Likewise there is a *unique* pair $(\alpha, x') \in f$ with $x' \in V_\alpha$. By unicity $x=x' \in U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha$. So $f$ has a unique pair with first component $\alpha$ and second component in $U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha$, and as this holds for all $\alpha \in J$, $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} (U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha)$. The reverse inclusion is similar.

The codomain argument is nonsense: $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ iff $f$ is a set of pairs such that

$$\forall \alpha \in J: \exists! (a,b) \in f: \exists x \in X_\alpha: (a,b)=(\alpha, x)$$

(this is set theory, we don't *have to* specify a codomain in advance like in category theory or topology (when considering a map between *spaces*) e.g.). A possible codomain can be computed from the set of pairs using standard axioms.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133350/discussion-on-answer-by-henno-brandsma-definition-of-j-tuple-j-is-an-index).

Comment: Do you get notifications, whenever someone send comment in chat room, because I don’t get any notifications?

Comment: @user264745 I usually do, yes.