# The Cartesian product of a (finite) family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on how to understand the notation, and application, of the cartesian product for a family of sets. In particular, Devlin (the Joy of Sets, p15) gives:

Let $x_i, i \in I$ be a family of sets. The *cartesian product* of the family {$x_i | i \in I$} is defined to be the set

$\prod_{i \in I} x_i = \{ f \mid (f:I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} x_i) \land (\forall i \in I)(f(i) \in x_i) \}$.

Devlin says this is a second definition of the cartesian product, different from the first. But, I am unclear how this definition works. I have checked this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177357/cartesian-products-of-families-in-halmos-book), and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438884/ordered-n-tuples-as-cartesian-products-of-indexed-families), and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630518/trouble-with-the-notion-of-cartesian-product-of-a-family?rq=1) but I am still lost.

How I (mis?)understand it is, suppose I have:

$x_a = \{ 0,1 \}, x_b = \{ 2,3,4 \}$, and $x_c = \{ 3,4,5 \}$ with $I = \{ a,b,c \}$.

Then the family of set $X$ = {$x_i$|$i \in I$} for $i \in \{ a,b,c \}$. In this example, $X = \{ \{ 0,1 \}, \{ 2,3,4 \}, \{ 3,4,5 \} \}$.

In this example then, would be the cartesian product of: $x_a \times x_b \times x_c$. But, I am unclear about the function part of the definition: $f:I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} x_i$. The definition states that the function maps the index set to the union of the family of sets.

In my example:
$\bigcup_{i \in I} = \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$ because, $\bigcup_{i \in I} = \{ a \mid(\exists x_i \in X)(a \in x_i) \}$.

So, my thinking is that I am creating a set of functions that map $I$ to $\bigcup_{i \in I}$. So:

$a \to 0, a \to 1, b \to 2, b \to 3, b \to 4, c \to 3, c \to 4, \text { and } c \to 5$

But this is clearly not a cartesian product, so I must have gone wrong somewhere. Can anybody point me in the right direction? (Also, is this understanding of a cartesian product essential if I understand the first definition given: $x_1 \times x_2 \times ... \times x_n = \{ (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \mid a_1 \in x_1 \land a_2 \in x_2 \land ... \land a_n \in x_n \}$).

Thank you!

Comment: $\{ x_i \}_{i \in I}$ is a *family* of sets, i.e. every $x_i$ is a set. The key point is that the "index set" $I$ is whatever (and not the usual $\mathbb N$).

Comment: It is defined as a set of functions $f$; what is a single element $f$? it is a function from $I$ and this part is like considering a numerical sequence $\{ a_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ where the $i$-th element is the value of the function associate to the index $i$.

Comment: What is $\bigcup_i x_i$? is simply the collection of all elements of the sets $x_i$. Thus, the single function $f$ associate to the $i$-th value an element of that "collection" with the simple rule that $f(i) \in x_i$.

Comment: So, following your example, an element of the cartesian product will be a function $f$ such that to $a$ associates an element of $x_a$: let it $0$, that is $f(a)=0$ and so on: $f(b)=2, f(c)=3$. This is the "uple", corresponding to the usual definition of *pair*: $(0,2) \in x_a \times x_b$.

Comment: In conclusion, if a function $f$ like that is a single "uple", then the cartesian product is the set of ALL such functions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment so much @MauroALLEGRANZA, that has clarified a lot! So, to check I have it, a different example would be $f(a) = 1, f(b) = 4, f(c) = 4$ would also be in $f$ and correspond to the "uple" (1,4,4)?

Comment: Exactly........ Why a function? In order to keep track of the "order", because we want $(1,4,4)$ and not $\{ 1,4,4 \}$. The second one is equal to $\{ 4,1,4 \}$ while the first one is different from $(4,1,4)$.

Comment: Thanks! It is starting to make sense, slowly!